# Write text into a div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a header with a drop down menu that is in an individual html file (Header.html). I call on that header on my final page (Page.html) with jquery (load) which "writes" my header into a fixed div of my final page.

I'd like to display the title of my individual page, contained in that page inside a div of the header.

I think I should use something like .text() but I don't really understand how it works : how do I declare where the Title is found, how do I tell it to write it in a certain div ?

I've searched but only found solutions for what seems to be more complicated problems.

Thanks for any helps or tips.

Comment: May I suggest posting some code?

Comment: have a look at  `.html()`, e.g. `.html("your text")`.

Comment: So basically you want to send a variable when loading your header so it displays the correct page title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something like this, a callback to your load function:

```
$('#header').load('/header.html', function(htmlResponse) {
    $(htmlResponse).find('#textre-titre').text('My title');
});
```

But I think a more optimal solution would be to have your header be a php file that accepts a post value to print the title that  you could send in your load function

```
$('#header').load('/header.php', {title: 'My title'});
```

And in header.php

```
<div id="textre-titre"><? echo $_POST['title']?></div>
```

Comment: Couldn't find how to make the load/html response solution work, but the simple PHP trick did it, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all give the `div` tag an `id` attribute

```
<div id='header'><div>
```

then before closing `</body>` tag include following snippet:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){  
        $('#header').html('your text');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can also use `.text()` if you are only writing plain text to the div. `.html()` supports markup as well.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure where to include these, I already have a div in Header.html (Texte-titre) where I want to write the text, but I can't seem to find where the script should go in Page.html